# Add payment link in WooCommerce customer invoice emails /failed order emails?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, orders

I recently noticed that customer invoice emails are missing a pay link. I tried various themes and disabled all other plugins and no luck.

Here is how the all come through even if payment has failed: http://prntscr.com/s9x8o5

I see what appears to be the correct code in the customer invoice template http://prntscr.com/s9x902 but it’s not working for some reason. This line never shows even if the order status is failed.

Any ideas on how I can get the payment link back in there? Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: Try below code and update the question accordingly

Comment: Please check if your order status is Pending. IIRC, the pay link is supposed to show if order is Pending.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the order object in the top of the email, if the object is correct.

```
/**
 * Executes the e-mail header.
 *
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
<?php

echo '<pre>$order:-';
print_r( $order );
echo '</pre>';

?>
<?php if ( $order->has_status( 'pending' ) ) { ?>
    <p>
    <?php
    printf(
        wp_kses(
            /* translators: %1$s Site title, %2$s Order pay link */
            __( 'An order has been created for you on %1$s. Your invoice is below, with a link to make payment when you’re ready: %2$s', 'woocommerce' ),
            array(
                'a' => array(
                    'href' => array(),
                ),
            )
        ),
        esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ),
        '<a href="' . esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Pay for this order', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>'
    );
    ?>
    </p>

<?php } else { ?>
    <p>
    <?php
    /* translators: %s Order date */
    printf( esc_html__( 'Here are the details of your order placed on %s:', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ) );
    ?>
    </p>
    <?php
}
```